# Change component from contentpane on radiobuttton mouse click event

Tags: java, swing

Hi i created a swing application which contain combobox on contentpane..My need is when i click any combobox textbox must be removed and replace a combo box.!

```
  txtSearch = new JTextField();
            txtSearch.setBounds(10, 11, 107, 22);
            getContentPane().add(txtSearch);
            txtSearch.setColumns(10);

 category = new JRadioButton("Search By Category");
    category.setActionCommand("category");
    buttonGroup.add(category);
    category.setBounds(10, 118, 140, 23);
    getContentPane().add(category);
```

**mouse clieck event for category radio button**

```
@Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                getContentPane().remove(txtSearch);


                getContentPane().add(comboCategory);


            }
```

**mouse click event for title radio button**

```
@Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            getContentPane().add(txtSearch);

                getContentPane().remove(comboCategory);

                //getContentPane().add(txtSearch);


            }
```

i already done click event for category radio button.it working perfectly
But when i click title radio button it does not change back to text box..!!

Comment: *"textbox must be removed and replace a textbox.!"*  What?  Why replace one 'textbox' with another?  It's better just to change the text in the existing text box.  Other tips:  1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). ..

Comment: .. 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: I'd add 4) For JRadioButton, JButton or JCheckBox don't use MouseListener but ActionListener to listen when the button is pressed. See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: @dic19  Yes, that is a worthy point (4).